# Creating a for loop inside javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a chart into my website (FusionCharts), i don't want to manually define each bar. Is there any way to implement a for loop here? ( for(i =1; i<=11; i++) My issue is the '{' & '},'

The FusionCharts example is as follows

```
    "data": [{
        "label": "Jan",
        "value": "420000"
    }, {
        "label": "Feb",
        "value": "810000"
    }, {
        "label": "Mar",
        "value": "720000"
    }, {
        "label": "Apr",
        "value": "550000"
    }, {
        "label": "May",
        "value": "910000"
    }, {
        "label": "Jun",
        "value": "510000"
    }, {
        "label": "Jul",
        "value": "680000"
    }]
}
}
);
```

My only solution was to have the below in the for loop, but it ofcourse wont work with the brackets.

```
     {
        "label": "xxxx",
        "value": "xxxxx"
    },
```

...

```
    for (i=1; i<=11; i==) 
     {

        {
        "label": "xxxx",
        "value": "xxxxx"
    },

     }
```

I realise im probably being stupid in this situation so thanks for any advice

Comment: `for` loops are statements. You can't use them inside array initializers like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you can write

```
data.push({
    "label": "xxxx",
    "value": "xxxxx"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it ofcourse wont work with the brackets.

It will:

```
for (i=1; i<=11; i++) 
{
    data.push({
        "label": "xxxx",
        "value": "xxxxx"
   });
}
```

...but you still have to get the label and value from somewhere.

---

Side note: Don't forget to declare `i`, lest ye fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: I've actually tried this out and its refusing to display the graph still, the code i've used is basically identical.

      for (i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
         data.push(
          {
         "label": 1,
  "value": 1
  },)
}

Comment: @MartinGanly: That will definitely create an array with a series of objects, each with `label: 1` and `value: 1`...

Answer (score 0):

... upon your required format, you can play as per below;

```
let data = [{
        "label": "Jan",
        "value": "420000"
    }, {
        "label": "Feb",
        "value": "810000"
    }, {
        "label": "Mar",
        "value": "720000"
    }, {
        "label": "Apr",
        "value": "550000"
    }, {
        "label": "May",
        "value": "910000"
    }, {
        "label": "Jun",
        "value": "510000"
    }, {
        "label": "Jul",
        "value": "680000"
    }];


var arr =[];
var arr2 =[];

data.forEach( (obj) => {
  console.log(obj.label, obj.value);
  let ttlArrOpt1 = arr.push(obj.label, obj.value);
  // or option 2:
  let ttlArrOpt2 = arr2.push(obj.label + " = " + obj.value)

}
);
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);

let arrOpt2 = arr.join('/');
console.log(arrOpt2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rawData = ''; 
for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){    
        rawData = rawData.concat('{"label": "'+ ( i + 2 ) +'","value": "'+     i +'"},');
}
rawData = rawData.substring(0, rawData.length - 1);
rawData = '{"data"\: ['.concat(rawData , ']}');
var finalData = JSON.parse(rawData);
```